# CKeditor remove symbol $100

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I Have plugin CKeditor, when I Write text with "$100", ckeditor remove this string, when I save. How I Can resolve this problem?

JS:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
        CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'dragresize,jsplus_stat';
        var editorMd = CKEDITOR.replace('edit_md', {contentsCss: '/css/tools.css'});
        var editorRu = CKEDITOR.replace('edit_ru', {contentsCss: '/css/tools.css'});
        var editorEn = CKEDITOR.replace('edit_en', {contentsCss: '/css/tools.css'});
        //CKFinder.SetupCKEditor( null, '/js/ckfinder3/' );
        //CKEDITOR.config.wordcount = {showWordCount: true}
        CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
        CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=imagesnew';
        CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
        CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
        CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=imagesnew';
        CKEDITOR.config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
        //CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null);
        /*
         CKFinder.setupCKEditor( null, {
         skin: 'moono',
         swatch: 'b',
         onInit: function( finder ) {
         finder.on( 'files:choose', function( evt ) {
         var file = evt.data.files.first();
         //console.log( 'Selected: ' + file.get( 'name' ) );
         } );
         }
         } );
         */
        /*
         CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
         config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
         config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
         config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/js/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
         config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
         config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
         config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/js/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
         };
         */
        jQuery('#date_show').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en',
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
        });
    });
    function openMedia() {
        window.open('<?=$adminRoot . 'news/media/id/' . $item->id . '/'?>', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Code when I load CKeditor, and config this. Please help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is a JavaScript application. It has nothing to do with saving data. I also haven't heard of any built-in filter removing "$100" string. Things you might want to check:

1. Run `CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstanceName.getData();`. If "$100" is not there, please look for some third-party script reacting to `\$\d` pattern or something similar. Another thing to check would be a third-party CKEditor plugins. Perhaps you have some "before save" plugin which filters out such strings.
2. Please check your server-side code if it doesn't contain any filter removing strings starting with `$`. Debugging whole request (when editor data is submitted) might also help you find out where exactly "$100" gets removed.